# Compute cone angle (cos) given side and hypotenuse vectors at time 0 and world matrix at time 1

Tags: lighting, mathematics

I need a formula for the cosine of a cone, given normalized side vector, normalized hypotenuse vector at time 0 and world matrix at time 1. This is needed to implement custom spotlights in a level editor which can be tweaked by user via standard translation/rotation/scale gizmo.

The cosine of the cone at time 0 (when world matrix is Identity) can be computed via this formula:

```
Vector3.Dot(side, hypotenuse);
```

I tried this formula for time 1:

```
Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Transform(side, matrix)), Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Transform(hypotenuse, matrix)));
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Despite its name, `Vector3.Transform()` does not transform a vector but a point. The unwanted side effect is that the translation part gets added to your vector. If you want to actually transform a vector, you need to use `Vector3.TransformNormal()`, which will omit the translation part:

```
Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.TransformNormal(side, matrix)),
            Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.TransformNormal(hypotenuse, matrix)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was looking for this method for my other work. But for the formula in question, my humble tests show that there is no difference whether you use Transform or TransformNormal. It also does not allow to optimize out the normalization part - you still need to use the original vectors and normalize them after the transformation.

Comment: If your tests show no difference between `Transform` and `TransformNormal`, you are not testing enough :-) Try adding a translation part to your tranformation matrix.

Comment: You were right, I was doing translation separately and I did not realize that. But surprisingly, with translation added, only Transform works, even though it works a little funky... I don't know what I am doing wrong but that's how things are... I guess I will keep them separate for now.

Comment: @cubrman "it works a little funky" equals doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the formula was correct. I built my side and hypotenuse vectors at time 0 incorrectly. My mistake was that I used normalized vectors at time 0 in the transformation, while you need to use the original ones. You can indeed find the cosine at time 1 with this formula:

```
Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Transform(side, matrix)), Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Transform(hypotenuse, matrix)));
```